# Cognito renewal of refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

Just implemented an OAuth2 authentication with AWS Cognito and came across this issue:

I am re-generating an *id_token* with my *refresh_token* using this endpoint:

`/oauth2/token`
`grant-type: refresh_token`

but when my *refresh_token* is expired, I don't want the user to go through the login process again.
Is there any way of "refresh the *refresh_token*"?

Also, I don't want my *refresh_token* to have infinite (or 9999 years) of validity time.

What should I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot get a fresh refresh token without having the user sign in again. That's the whole point of a refresh token. You can have a refresh token for a reasonable time like a month and then forcefully invalidate it if user signs out though.